# Devise get user by reset_password_token

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm trying to create password rules to devise recoverable password change.
I did a super class via passwords_controller.rb, but I need to check the user role before aply the rules, but all that I have there is the reset_password_token.

Comment: Can you share the relevant code that you have tried. Please post it in the question.

Comment: can you explain your requirement in detail?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Assuming your model is User:

> User.with_reset_password_token(your_token_here)

[Source](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/Devise%2FModels%2FRecoverable%2FClassMethods%3Awith_reset_password_token)

Comment: you save my day!

Comment: Can someone please select this as the answer. Only upvoted once, but in my mind I have upvoted this a thousand times.

Answer (score 2):

Older versions of devise don't contain this method: with_reset_password_token(your_token_here)

So you can create this method in your model:

```
def self.with_password_reset_token(password_reset_token)
    generated_password_reset_token = Devise.token_generator.digest(self, :reset_password_token, password_reset_token)
    return self.find_by(reset_password_token: generated_password_reset_token)
  end
```

Then you can call this method from your model like this:

```
user = User.with_password_reset_token(your_token_here)
```

We are using user model here in the example.

Comment: thanks! Devise 4.8.1 but i had to add your method and it works!

Answer (score 1):

To answer the title of your question it would simply be

```
User.find_by_reset_password_token(reset_password_token_here)
```

But your question is bit unclear beyond that.

Answer (score -1):

Very late to the party here but `User.find_by(reset_password_token: <token>)` works as well.